# javascript keep aspect ration rotation in mobile

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, device-orientation

I couldn't find a proper answer to my case.

We have an add-on for websites which has a small UI with small icons text etc.
In mobile, upon rotation, I want to maintain a proper aspect ration and change the size of the images a bit.
I couldn't find useful guidelines for that.

For example, we have a 50x50 icon, which looks great on portrait in LG G2, but when going to landscape it should be resized to 25x25 or 30x30 and so does all the other elements.
I always see examples talking about MAX_WIDTH of an image etc. but couldn't make the connection to my case.

I don't use JQuery BTW

Comment: I am not quite sure, why dont you just use CSS: 
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) .icon{ width: 25px; height: 25px }

Comment: Hi,I am running cross browser in many devices and browsers.
Not sure that 25x25 is the best for all, would like something more general.
Thanks.